# Trigger after merge successful?

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab-ci

I have this .gitlab-ci.yml script --- it triggers if I push directly on the master. How can I trigger this if there's a successful merge on the master branch?

```
before_script:
  - apt-get update -qq
  - apt-get install -qq git
  # Setup SSH deploy keys
  - 'which ssh-agent || ( apt-get install -qq openssh-client )'
  - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
  - echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | tr -d '\r' | ssh-add - > /dev/null
  - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
  - '[[ -f /.dockerenv ]] && echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config'

deploy_staging:
  type: deploy
  environment:
    name: staging
    url: domain.com
  script:
    - ssh user@domain.com "cd /server/directory && git fetch && git pull origin master && exit"
  only:
    - master
```

Answer (score 0):

Like the reference notes

```
test:
  stage: test
  script: ./test
  only:
  - merge_requests
```

see https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/merge_request_pipelines/index.html

Comment: I tried that by changing my only: - master into merge_requests but doesn't seem to work

Comment: and here's why **Since the build and deploy jobs don’t have the only: merge_requests parameter, they will not run in the merge request.**